# Test case for Deadline IO Scheduler

Tags: io, block-device, scheduling, bios, mmc

I am trying to measure the impact of Deadline IO scheduler on the performance of Block IO.

My setup includes:

- Kernel Version: 4.4.154
- Storage device: eMMC 64GB
- Distribution: VERSION="18.04.4 LTS (Bionic Beaver)

I have tried the The Andrew Morton Interactive Workload (AMIW)
as suggested in
https://lwn.net/Articles/10874/
i.e.
Flush lots of stuff to disk (I start a dbench xxx, or do a dd
if=/dev/zero of=test_file bs=64k), and then time a cat dir/*.c where
dir/ holds lots of source files.

But I see more or less the same amount of time taken for read for [cfq], [deadline] and [noop].

Why is that?

What test case should I use to see a substantial improvement in performance?

Comment: I suggest you have a look there https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=linux5-io-sched&num=1 in order to see the different tests achieved. Then you can even download the full testsuite if interested https://www.phoronix-test-suite.com/ in order to run it yourself on your own hardware.

Comment: And BTW... there is no much thing to optimize regarding the regular flow of a dd command.

Comment: I found this script measuring performance of IO schedulers. https://github.com/m1d1/sched-bench/blob/master/sched-bench.sh